# Im trying to set column width on excel 2010 using setcolumnwidth

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to set the `colunm` width with `setColumnWidth(rowindex, width)` using POI,problem is the width is in double and the function above only accept Int

I tried using `autosizecolumn` but its still living underpopulated space in the column, problem i think is the font mismatch between excel and java

code

```
           RowTotal = NewSheet.createRow(0);
           cell1 = RowTotal.createCell(0);
           cell1.setCellValue("Row Name/Label");
           cell1 = RowTotal.createCell(1);
           cell1.setCellValue("Sum of premium payable");
           cell1 = RowTotal.createCell(2);
           cell1.setCellValue("Sum of arrears payable");

           NewSheet.setColumnWidth(0, 3755.84);
           NewSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 5519.68);;
           NewSheet.setColumnWidth(2, 5207.36);
```

Comment: You can get int value from double using intValue().

Comment: `Sheet.autoSizeColumn(0, 3755.84)` will not even compile. And [Sheet.setColumnWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-) describes what `width` exactly is.

Comment: its suppose to be setColumnWidth, thanks. its setting the width of column 0

Comment: i want the width to be 3755.84 but the function setColumnWidth wont accept it becouse its double

Comment: "i want the width to be 3755.84 ": Why? Why not 3756 or 3755? As long as Calibri 11 is used as the default font in Excel's default cell style, both integers will give a column width of 14 in Excel. Also 3766 leads to a column width of 14 in Excel if Calibri 11 is the default font. Default font does not mean it must be the font into all cells but must be the font in Excel's default cell style.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass double value to setColumnWidth as well as to autosizecolumn because both the methods of Apache POI accepts int value as parameters.
Methods of Apache POI:
1. autoSizeColumn(int column)
   Adjusts the column width to fit the contents.
2. setColumnWidth(int columnIndex, int width)
   Set the width (in units of 1/256th of a character width)
you can refer to https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html
for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
NewSheet.getColumnHelper().setColWidth(0, 3755.84);
NewSheet.getColumnHelper().setCustomWidth(0, true);
```

I'm not sure if the second line is necessary but if you manually change the width of a column in excel, it will automatically set CustomWidth = true. So I just add it to be safe.

Comment: [ColumnHelper.setColWidth(0, 3755.84)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/helpers/ColumnHelper.html#setColWidth-long-double-) leads to XML in `/xl/worksheets/sheet?.xml`: `<cols><col min="1" max="1" bestFit="true" customWidth="true" width="3755.84" collapsed="false"/>...</cols>`. But maximum column width is 255.00. And so Excel renders this column having column width 255. So setting column width 3755.84 is useless at all.

Comment: You are right. The width should be 3755.84/256 or whatever double number between 0 and 255.

Comment: Thanks, but does the columnHelper work with HSSF or just XSSF ?